# Combine object array if same key value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know how to combine array values if same `id` in javascript.

I tried below code

```
let result = this.getData(obj);

function getData(obj) {
 return obj.map(e=>({procode: e.prcode, id: e.id});
}
```

```
var obj= [
  {
    id: "1",
    prcode: "dessert"
  },{
    id: "1",
    prcode: "snacks"
  }, {
   id: "2",
   prcode: "cafe"
 }, {
  id: "4",
  prcode: "all"
}
]
```

Expected Output:

```
result = [
 {id: "1", prcode: "dessert,snacks"},
 {id: "2", prcode: "cafe"},
 {id: "4", prcode: "all"}
]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `reduce` alongside `Object.values()`:

```js
var obj = [
  { id: "1", prcode: "dessert" },
  { id: "1", prcode: "snacks" },
  { id: "2", prcode: "cafe" },
  { id: "4", prcode: "all" }
]

const out = obj.reduce((a, v) => {
  if(a[v.id]) {
    a[v.id].prcode = [a[v.id].prcode, v.prcode].join(',')
  } else {
    a[v.id] = v
  }
  return a
}, {})
console.log(Object.values(out))
```

Comment: Nice this is perfect, helped me quite a bit, thank you very much Kobe!

Comment: @jamesbar Glad I could help :)